# Problems with changing colors in chart winform

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, colors, series

I have a list with checked checkboxes. All the items on the list is painted on a chart as a line. When I uncheck an Item, this item must be painted as a gray line. This do also happen, but NeXT item in the list gets the color of the item before it was grayed out. Can't really figure out why. Is it something in chart. Heres my code.

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
  if (readyForChangingColor)
  {
     foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
     {
        if (series.LegendText == e.Item.Text)
        {
           // if unchecked checkbox. Make the line gray
           if (!e.Item.Checked)
           {
              series.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
           }
        }
     }
  }
}

//Adding a serie to chart

var NewDataSeries = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
{
                Name = "SomeLogData" + Convert.ToString(NumberOfSets),
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
                IsXValueIndexed = false,
                ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line,
};
// Add the new series to the chart.
this.chart1.Series.Add(NewDataSeries);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors are assigned automatically according to a palette, unless a color has been set explicitly. So the next series down gets the freed up color.

To avoid this, you need to explicitly set the colors of all series.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.palette(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want it to set the `Color` of a `DataPoint`, not of the whole `Series`.

To do so you simply set it:

```
   yourDataPoint.Color = Color.Gray;
```

Note that this will set the color of the Point and (where applicable) the line coming to it from the **previous** Point. So the **first** Point's color will not show in a line segment..

Example of both Colors:

```
Series S = chart1.Series[0];
S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
S.Color = Color.Fuchsia;
S.Points.AddXY(1, 10);    S.Points.AddXY(2, 20);
S.Points.AddXY(3, 60);    S.Points.AddXY(4, 10);
DataPoint yourDataPoint = S.Points[2];
yourDataPoint.Color = Color.Gray;
```

[image: Line Chart][image: Point Chart]